# Disabling -Werror for dkms

Tags: c, linux, installation, dkms

I am currently trying to install a kernel module to Ubuntu. I've copied the source file for the module into `/usr/src/applespi-0.1`.

Then, I did

```
sudo dkms install -m applespi -v 0.1
```

and got

```
Building module:
cleaning build area....
make KERNELRELEASE=4.4.0-31-generic....(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-31-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/applespi/0.1/build/make.log for more information.
```

make.log: https://pastebin.com/ySsHrgUt

My goal is to disable -Werror for when compiling this source file. However, I can't seem to find the Makefile with the -Werror flag.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I've located the Makefile by running dkms with `--verbose` and commenting the `-Werror` flag. Thank you anyway, guys.